# How to know if an existing expression or entity is a solution to  =  (Matrix Equation)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am still baffled on how I can prove if something is a solution to  =  (Matrix Equation). Do I need to know how to solve its matrix first despite having a lacking amount of given values?

An example scenario would involve:

If <sub>1</sub> and <sub>2</sub> are solutions to the linear system  =, then w = 1/4u<sub>1</sub>  +3/4u<sub>2</sub> is also a solution to Ax =b.

Thus, how can I prove if this statement is true or false?

Your responses would indeed help me a lot on this one as I am freshly exposed with this part about matrix equations. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried plugging $w$ into the equation and expanding it using the properties of matrix multiplication?

Comment: Not yet at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u_1 $ and $u_2$ are solutions to the linear system $ =$ then
$$Au_1=b,\quad Au_2=b$$
$$\Rightarrow Aw=A(\frac{1}{4}u_1+\frac{3}{4}u_2)=\frac{1}{4}Au_1+\frac{3}{4}Au_2=b$$
All you need is $Ac=cA$ for any scalar c

Comment: Oh I see, thus by utilizing this way, especially through "Ac=cA  for any scalar c", the given statement above is going to be true?

Comment: As long as the coefficients add up to 1, yes. Even if one of the numbers is negative.

Comment: Ok ok, will take note of that condition that involves its coefficients. Thank you very much for this one @Kyle!!!

Comment: You should accept the answer if it solves your problem.